# How do I keep track of related record ID's in ASP.Net core for updating child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I'm new at asp.net core and a beginner programmer. I'm in the process of creating an application that requires a page that updates the items and it's child items on the same page. Making the parent data update is easy but I'm a bit lost on how to update the child items.

Here's a simplified model of the items and child items:

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestChild> TestChildren { get; set; }
}

public class TestChild
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string ChildName { get;set; }
    public int TestID { get;set; }
    public Test Test {get; set; }
}
```

I render this out to the user on a Razor web page using similar code to this:

```
...
    <input asp-for="Test.Name" class="form-control" />
    @foreach (var child in Model.Test.TestChildren)
    {
        <input name="TC.@child.ID" value="@child.ChildName">
    }
...
```

My plan was to use the Name field in the child input box to return the ID of each child record and this in conjunction with the value field would allow me to update the correct record. This means that when the form was posted the data returned might be similar to the following:

```
TC.4 = "Child 1"
TC.6 = "Child 2"
TC.9 = "Child 3"
```

Where the .X is the ID of the related child and name is it's new / updated name. Really what I would like is to somehow return a dictionary where the key is the ID and the value is the Name.

However if I use the above code when the form is posted I don't know what type to declare the variable as, that is passed to the onpost function as per bellow:

```
public async Task<IactionResult> OnPostAsync(int id, ???????????)
{
    ...
    What variable type should I use to map to the data above?
}
```

So  my questions are:

1. Is this the best way of updating child records?
2. Is their an easier/better way to link a child records ID and value and pass it back to the onpost function?
3. If what I have is correct what do I have to declare the variable as in the onpost?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't think it's the best way.

You don't need to add the receive parameter in the post method. Because you pass the `Test` data to the page, your code behind should have a field of `Test` type,right?

You only need to ensure that when you submit the view the model is the `Test` type. You need to make sure that `the name of children is consistent with the hierarchical relationship of the model`.

And you need to `add the ID field as a hidden field` in the view to confirm which data you are updating.

Here is the code:

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MydbContext _context;

        public IndexModel (MydbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Test Test { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            // here is an example to pass data to view.
            Test = _context.Test.Include(x => x.TestChildren).Where(x => x.ID == 5).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
          //the Test parameter will change which is contains the value you changed.
           var newtest =   _context.Test.Include(x => x.TestChildren).Where(x => x.ID == Test.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            newtest.Name = Test.Name;
            newtest.TestChildren = Test.TestChildren;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1_razor_page.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TestChild";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var i = 0;
}

<h1>Index</h1>
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Test.ID" class="form-control" hidden />
    <input asp-for="Test.Name" class="form-control" /> 
    @foreach (var child in Model.Test.TestChildren)
    {
        <input asp-for="@child.ID" name="Test.TestChildren[@i].ID"     hidden/>
        <input asp-for="@child.ChildName" name="Test.TestChildren[@i].ChildName"  />
        i++;
    }
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much you really cleared things up for me!